# Scraping Dynamic Content - Page Source Different than Website

Tags: python, dynamic, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the content from this website:

http://america.aljazeera.com/search.html?q=blizzard

The page source is different than what appears on the page and I think it is because of the dynamic content. Are there any simple ways to scrape this page the way that it actually appears? I am using python.

Comment: Take a look on **Selenium**. This drives a entire browser, is better to get sources when is dinamically rendered. > http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: And... [The magic](https://www.solver.io/wp/2012/10/25/python-selenium-how-to-get-the-html-source/).